# Simultaneous microphone recording and audio playback (WP 8.1 XAML)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Using the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control and [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241124) class, I am trying to record microphone input and play audio at the same time.

As soon as I start recording, whatever track is playing mutes.  I don't think it stops, because it continues playing after the recording has stopped.  I have added hooks into several events on the MediaElement and none are being fired.  For example, CurrentStateChanged, MediaEnded, MediaFailed etc.

Recording code:

```
public async void InitializeMediaCapture()
{
    _mediaCaptureManager = new MediaCapture();
    var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
    settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
    settings.MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Other;            

    await _mediaCaptureManager.InitializeAsync(settings);
}

private async void CaptureAudio()
{         
  _recordStorageFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
  var recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateM4a(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
  await _mediaCaptureManager.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, this._recordStorageFile); 
  //audio playback stops on preceding line of code 
}
```

I use .Play() on the MediaElement to play the audio, with the control in my XAML and the audio source set there.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="playbackElement"  
              Source="ms-appx:///Audio/Song.mp3" 
              AutoPlay="False" />
```

I have also tried playing the audio as BackgroundAudio, but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1.Never set a MediaElement's Source in XAML, unless that XAML is on a page that you navigate to after asking the user for consent.

2.Check to see if background music is playing and then set the source (in code).
Note: If you set the source and then immediately call Play(), the Play() will have no affect since the MediaElement will still be in the "Opening" state, instead set "AutoPlay = true" (works from code)

Here's a [Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oren/archive/2010/12/02/wp7-silverlight-gotcha-setting-the-source-on-a-mediaelement-will-stop-background-music-playback.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, after modifying my code to do the that - the audio playback still mutes as soon as I begin recording.  I know the playback does not stop, because I hear the audio after I stop recording and it wasn't in a paused state, rather it was playing during the entire recording (just muted).

It mutes when this line is executed:

`code`await _mediaCaptureManager.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, this._recordStorageFile);